# Suppose $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_{3},\alpha_4$ are the roots of the equation $x^4+x^2+1=0.$ Then, find the sum of each roots raised to the 4th power.

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

Suppose $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \alpha_{3}$ and $\alpha_4$ are the roots of the equation $x^{4}+x^{2}+1=0.$ Then, find the value of $\alpha_{1}^{4}+\alpha_{2}^{4}+\alpha_{3}^{4}+\alpha_{4}^{4}.$

I attempted the problem as follows:

> Given, $x^{4}+x^{2}+1=0,$ and we assume $z=x^2.$ Then, $g(z)=z^2+z+1=0.$ Then the roots of $g(z)$ are $\omega,\omega^2.$ Now,$x^2=z,$ so the original roots of the (given) equation is $\pm\sqrt\omega,\sqrt{\omega^2}=\pm\omega.$ Let $\alpha_1=\sqrt\omega,\alpha_2=-\sqrt\omega,\alpha_3=\omega,\alpha_4=-\omega.$ Now, $\alpha_{1}^{4}+\alpha_{2}^{4}+\alpha_{3}^{4}+\alpha_{4}^{4}=2\omega^2+2\omega^4=2(\omega^2+\omega)=-2.$

Is the way I presented the proof looks correct? Should I include more details? I feel my proof works though.

Comment: Your solution is not clear. Specially the way you solved the degree-2 equation.

Comment: @NoChance Yes, you might be correct. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There is one omission and one mistake in your solution.
You need to show that $\omega=\omega^2$ by numerically expressing the roots of $z^2+x+1$

Then further down the statement $\sqrt{\omega^2}=\pm \omega$ is false; you may want to change it to something like $x^2=z\Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt z=\pm \sqrt{\omega}$.

Comment: That's a good point, @WindSoul. Indeed , that's a logical gap in it.

Comment: @StephenSmith You can argue that $(z-1)g(z)=z^3 - 1$ so your $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity, and the other root must be $\overline\omega=\frac{1}{\omega}=\omega^2$.

Comment: @WindSoul Your now deleted answer could have worked more easily if you just used $\alpha_i^4 =-\alpha_i^2 - 1$ to calculate $\sum\alpha_i^4 = - 4 - \sum\alpha_i^2$ where $\sum\alpha_i^2 = (\sum\alpha_i)^2 - 2\sum\alpha_i\alpha_j = 0 - 2 \cdot 1$ by Vieta's relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct. Perhaps you should add what $\omega$ is and why the roots of $g(z)$ have the form as in your question.

You can alternatively do it without explicitly calculating the roots of $g(z)$. Call them $r_1, r_2$. Then the four roots of the given equation are $\pm \sqrt{r_i}$ and the sum of their fourth powers is $2(r_1^2+r_2^2)$. But $(r_1+r_2)^2 = r_1^2+r_2^2+2r_1r_2$. By Vieta $r_1+r_2 = -1 $ and $r_1r_2 = 1$.